# Preinstalls while building from source

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, vmware

Trying to build vmware tools for 32 bit Centos 7. Got error during `./configure`:

> Can't find include dir under /lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686

I suppose I should install some rpm's in order to get this directory? I even found I need  [kernel-plus-3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.src.rpm](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/centosplus/7.4.1708/x86_64/Packages/kernel-plus-devel-3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.x86_64.html). But I also suppose that it is only part of other more general package and I will need to install many more RPM's.

What logic I should follow in order to know what to install when I get such error? What is that package in my case?

#### UPDATE #1

```
$ gcc --version
...4.8.5 20150323

$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3,10,0 ...
gcc version 4.8.5 20150323
```

command

```
$ sudo yum install kernel-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package kernel-devel-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.centos.plus.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

command

```
$ ls /lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686/
build              modules.builtin      modules.modesetting  source
extra              modules.builtin.bin  modules.networking   updates
kernel             modules.dep          modules.order        weak-updates
modules.alias      modules.dep.bin      modules.softdep
modules.alias.bin  modules.devname      modules.symbols
modules.block      modules.drm          modules.symbols.bin
```

Comment: You seem to have clipped off the important information from `/proc/version`, namely the release number for the kernel you are using (output from `uname-r` would also show the kernel release).  An issue I see is that you are referencing different release versions in your post:  `3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686` != `3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.centos.plus.i686`.  These packages related to the kernel are strictly dependent on the release version of the running kernel, they must match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't install packages with `.src.rpm` suffix. Packages with this suffix needed for building RPM packages on own system.

VMware tools (also VBox tools) builds modules for your kernel. So it needs tools: compiler, kernel headers and build environment (Makefiles with specific predefined macros and couple of scripts).

Compiler provides by `gcc-<version>` package. You should ensure that you compiler version of running kernel (`cat /proc/version` => `gcc version`) and installed compiler package `gcc-<version>` are equal.

In Centos 7 `kernel-devel-$(uname -r)` package provides kernel headers with build environment.

Thats all you need to build VMware tools (or VBox tools).

---

**UPD:**

About `open-vm-tools` in Centos 7 and building it Centos 7. Centos 7 already have `open-vm-tools` in repository. It contains 2 systemd services (`vgauthd` and `vmtoolsd`), `vmware-<something>` programs and documentation.

I downloaded `open-vm-tools` (`yumdownloader --source open-vm-tools`) to see in `spec` file how it builds. In `%build` macro contains this instructions:

```
%configure \
    --without-kernel-modules \
    --enable-xmlsec1 \
    --disable-static
```

So package exactly doesn't provide modules. Where is modules?
In [github open-vm-tools README.md](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/blob/master/README.md) wrote:

> The open-vm-tools packages available with Linux distributions do not
>   include Linux drivers **because Linux drivers are available as part of
>   Linux kernel itself**.

It's true. I checked it in my Centos 7 (x86_64):

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name 'vm*'
/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/crypto/vmac.ko.xz
/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/vmwgfx
/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/vmwgfx/vmwgfx.ko.xz
/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/misc/vmw_balloon.ko.xz
/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/misc/vmw_vmci
/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/misc/vmw_vmci/vmw_vmci.ko.xz
/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/vmxnet3
/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/vmxnet3/vmxnet3.ko.xz
/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/scsi/vmw_pvscsi.ko.xz
/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/net/vmw_vsock
/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/net/vmw_vsock/vmw_vsock_virtio_transport.ko.xz
/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/net/vmw_vsock/vmw_vsock_virtio_transport_common.ko.xz
/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/net/vmw_vsock/vmw_vsock_vmci_transport.ko.xz
```

I downloaded your kernel version ([3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686](https://buildlogs.centos.org/c7.1708.u.x86_64/kernel/20170926144035/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i386/kernel-3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686.rpm)) and examine it content:

```
$ ls kernel-3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686.rpm
kernel-3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686.rpm
$ rpm2cpio kernel-3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686.rpm | cpio -idm # content will be extracted to boot and lib directories in this directory
$ find ./lib/ -name 'vm*'
./lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686/kernel/crypto/vmac.ko
./lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/vmwgfx
./lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/vmwgfx/vmwgfx.ko
./lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686/kernel/drivers/misc/vmw_balloon.ko
./lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686/kernel/drivers/misc/vmw_vmci
./lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686/kernel/drivers/misc/vmw_vmci/vmw_vmci.ko
./lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686/kernel/drivers/net/vmxnet3
./lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686/kernel/drivers/net/vmxnet3/vmxnet3.ko
./lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686/kernel/drivers/scsi/vmw_pvscsi.ko
./lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686/kernel/net/vmw_vsock
./lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686/kernel/net/vmw_vsock/vmw_vsock_virtio_transport.ko
./lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686/kernel/net/vmw_vsock/vmw_vsock_virtio_transport_common.ko
./lib/modules/3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.centos.plus.i686/kernel/net/vmw_vsock/vmw_vsock_vmci_transport.ko
```

So. Modules and tools provides by repository. You can rebuid tools but with `--without-kernel-modules`. If you want to rebuild modules (I doubt that is need) you should rebuild kernel package. Detail instruction present in [Centos Wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel).

---

**UPD2:**

Services setup. After successfully compiled tools were installed it's necessary to create 2 service files in `/usr/lib/systemd/system` with following content:

**vmtoolsd.service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Service for virtual machines hosted on VMware
Documentation=http://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools
ConditionVirtualization=vmware
Requires=vgauthd.service
After=vgauthd.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/vmtoolsd
TimeoutStopSec=5
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Also=vgauthd.service
```

**vgauthd.service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=VGAuth Service for open-vm-tools
Documentation=http://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools
ConditionVirtualization=vmware
PartOf=vmtoolsd.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/VGAuthService -s
TimeoutStopSec=5
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
RequiredBy=vmtoolsd.service
```

When they are will be created, you need reload modules dependencies with `systemctd daemon-reload`. After, you will can start services by calling `systemctl start vmtoolsd` or `systemctl start vgauthd`.

Comment: Conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75788/discussion-on-answer-by-yurij-goncharuk-preinstalls-while-building-from-source).

Comment: @vico I've just update my answer with information about modules.